# Cannot create pandas DataFrame from nested JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to retrieve `val1` and `val2` values from the following nested `json` file to build a pandas dataframe with two columns: `val1` and `val2`:

```
{
 'start': '2015-10-01 00:00',
 'end': '2015-10-01 01:00',
 'records': 
     {
        'val1': 
             [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5
             ],
         'val2':
             [
                0.1,
                0.5,
                0.2,
                0.1,
                0.0
             ],
         'val3': 'abc'
      }
}
```

This is what I do:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open(json_file) as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

df = json_normalize(data, 'records', ['val1', 'val2'], record_prefix='records_', errors='ignore')
```

However, I get this output:

```
    records_0   val1  val2
0   val1        NaN   NaN
1   val2        NaN   NaN
2   val3        NaN   NaN
```

The expected output:

```
val1   val2
1      0.1
2      0.5
3      0.2
4      0.1
5      0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your example, using json_normalize is not appropriate, because this method assumes that the base container is an array...

you can use another method:

```
with open(json_file) as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
  
pandas.DataFrame.from_dict( data= data["records"]  )
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your json to a variable or using `json.load`: then use `json_normalize`

[Here the example and the code]

```
import pandas as pd

json = {'start': '2015-10-01 00:00','end': '2015-10-01 01:00','records': {'val1': [1,2,3,4,5],'val2':[0.1,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.0],'val3': 'abc'}}

df = pd.json_normalize(json)

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
```

[image: 1]

If you want only 2 columns left, then just drop another column and decide which column you want to keep

[Here the example and the code]

```
for column in df.columns:
if column != 'val1' and column != 'val2':
    df = df.drop([column], axis = 1)
```

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2):

You can systematically pull out what you want.

```
js = {'start': '2015-10-01 00:00',
 'end': '2015-10-01 01:00',
 'records': {'val1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  'val2': [0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0],
  'val3': 'abc'}}

(pd.json_normalize(js["records"],"val1")
 .rename(columns={0:"val1"})
 .join(pd.json_normalize(js["records"],"val2"))
 .rename(columns={0:"val2"})
)
```

|  | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 4 | 0.1 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

You can define a list as `['val1','val2']` and initialize a dataframe and populate the elements of this new dataframe through use of a for loop such as

```
import json
import pandas as pd

l=['val1','val2']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=l)
with open('myfile.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file) 

for i in l:
    df[i]=data['records'][i]

df

   val1  val2
0     1   0.1
1     2   0.5
2     3   0.2
3     4   0.1
4     5   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The function expects an array of dictionary.

Just twist a bit .

```py
json_normalize({"val1":val1,"val2":val2} for val1,val2 in zip(data['records']['val1'],data['records']['val2']))
```